# Using a variable as identifier in a json array

Tags: javascript, json, variables, identifier

I'm wondering if it is possible to use assigned variables as identifier in a json array. When I tried this, I was getting some unexpected results:

(Code is simplified, parameters are passed in a different way)

```
var parameter = 'animal';
var value = 'pony';

Util.urlAppendParameters(url, {
  parameter: value
});


Util.urlAppendParameters = function(url, parameters) {
  for (var x in parameters) {
    alert(x);
  }
}
```

Now the alert popup says: 'parameter' instead of 'animal'. I know I could use a different method (creating an array and assigning every parameter on a new line), but I want to keep my code compact.

**So my question is: Is it possible to use a variable as an identifier in the json array, and if so, could you please tell me how?**

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can't use a variable as an identifier within an object literal like that. The parser is expecting a name there so you can't do much else but provide a string. Similarly you couldn't do something like this:

```
var parameter = 'animal';
var parameter = 'value'; //<- Parser expects a name, nothing more, so original parameter will not be used as name
```

The only work around if you really really want to use an object literal on a single line is to use eval:

```
Util.urlAppendParameters (url, eval("({" + parameter + " : value})");
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. Not that I'm going to use it (I sure don't really really want it :D), but I was really curious about how it could be solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

You will need to build your object in two steps, and use the `[]` property accessor:

```
var parameter = 'animal';
var value = 'pony';

var obj = {};
obj[parameter] = value;

Util.urlAppendParameters (url, obj);
```

I don't think *JSON Array* is the more correct term, I would call it *Object literal*.

Comment: Yeah, I already did that, but I just want to know if it ís possible, like in other programming languages (e.g. escaping with backticks, or just with a leading $ sign)

Sorry for the vague title, programming terminology is not my best skill.

Comment: @CMS we searched the internet for a solution for a long time and found it here, thx

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your needs you could also build your object with a helper function;

```
Util.createParameters = function(args) {
    var O = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i += 2)
        O[arguments[i]] = arguments[i + 1];
    return O
}

Util.urlAppendParameters (url, Util.createParameters(parameter, value, "p2", "v2"));
```